# Access control for Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to set access controls for Apache spark such that we can control which users can submit jobs via spark-submit. Ideally this would integrate with active directory so permissions signs could be controlled by ad groups.

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses Kerberos and that can be configured to work with Active Directory.
Check:

```
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html
https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/securing-your-apache-spark-applications
```

Some settings to consider:

```
spark.acls.enable # true 
spark.admin.acls # set to admin users 
spark.modify.acls # user who can modify
```